# Question regarding Java volatile keyword for reference types

Tags: java, class, volatile

I understand the volatile keyword in Java can make the read/write operations of reference variables and all primitives except long and double, atomic in nature.

I also know compound statements such as incrementing an integer, var++, are not atomic and should not be used in place of synchronized statements.

But what about this class?

```
public class Setter{

    private int num = 0;

    public int setNum(int numIn){
        num = numIn;
        return num;
    }
}
```

Now say you declare an instance of Setter as volatile.

```
public class Main {
     private volatile Setter s;

     public static void main(String[] args){
         s = new Setter();
         s.setNum(5);
     }
}
```

Is a call to the method setNum atomic?  Is this statement safe if multiple threads are calling it at once, each with different values?

What would be an example of using a volatile class in a proper way, and using it in an unsafe compound statement?

Comment: The first sentence is not a sentence, which makes it impossible to clearly interpret the rest of the question.

Comment: @bmargulies: then explain why it's wrong (yup, I know it's wrong) or use your mod points to edit the question instead of making a snarky comment.  You also realize do that your comment would not make any sense anymore should that question get edited and the first sentence changed right?  Question / wiki-style edit like / SO.  Do you speak it *******?

Comment: you're mistaken as to what *volatile* does in Java (that's what bmargulies lamely tried to explain).  For a start, if you declare *volatile long ...* you'll never be able to read a long "half-set" (say 32-hi bits set from one thread and 32-lo bits set from another thread).  That simply cannot happen.

Comment: obviously i'm mistaken thats why i'm asking this question

Comment: "Java Language Specification, Second Edition, Chapter 17, Threads and Locks" says "The load, store, read, and write actions on volatile variables are atomic, even if the type of the variable is double or long"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is a call to the method setNum atomic?***

No, it's not. It is only the reads / writes to `s` that would be volatile.

This can be compared with letting a `List` be `final`. This is not sufficient to make *the list* immutable, only the list-reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, that use of `volatile` only applies to the reference `s`, not the fields of the object it refers to.  You can't (safely) have multiple threads call `s.setNum(n)`.

You could, however, have a thread create a new `Setter` object, store a number into it, and then change `s` to refer to the new object instead of the old one.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to an object and the content of that object are different things. In your case, the reference (***that is prat of your Main class***) to the object is `volatile`, meaning that when you read/write the reference the *volatile* rules will apply. You can freely have another reference to the same object that is not volatile and *volatile* rules wont apply to it.